# Нейронные сети свертка / Замена цикла for в Python 3 / Ускорение скорости подсчета программы на Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети

**Вопрос отредактирован 21.11.2017г 21:08 (по московскому времени) :)**

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с ускорением подсчетов в программе на Python 3.

Задача и реализация:

Используется библиотека numpy.

**Задача:**

**Ускорить время выполнения кода ниже:**

**Код (Python 3)** (с моей точки зрения рабочий, но очень медленный,
на тестовой задаче выполняется, но на реальной не проверено, т.к. велико время подсчета):

```
    def count(self, A, n1, n2, syn_, type_):# подсчет
        result=[]
        i_=0

        #--------------------------------
        # Создаем списки и зануляем их элементы (реализация на мой взгляд не очень)
        result=np.random.random((len(A)-n1+1, len(A[0])-n2+1, len(A.T)))
        result[:]=0 # Конечный результат
        B=np.random.random((n1, n2, len(A.T)))
        B[:]=0 # Список B - часть входного списка (массива)
        #--------------------------------

        for i in range(0, len(A)-(n1-1)):# проход по строкам (-(n1-1) - элементы не проходим, т.к. они будут проверны на итерации len(A)-n1+1)
            A_=A[i:i+n1]# "урезаем" массив и берем нужные элементы
            for l in range(0, len(A[i])-(n2-1)):# проход по столбцам (-(n2-1) - элементы не проходим)
                for j in range(0, n1):# проход по элементам подаваемым на подсчет в свертку
                    B[j]=A_[j][l:l+n2]# "урезаем" массив и берем нужные элементы

                # ++++++++++++
                # умножаем и суммируем (требуется двойная сумма (по двум мерностям),
                # суммируются все нужные элементы (остается N чисел,
                # где N - количество картинок))
                result[i][l]=sum(sum(syn_.dot(B)))# numpy.dot() - произведение массивов, в данном случае метод (syn_.dot(B)), есть "синоним" numpy.dot(syn_, B)
                # ++++++++++++
        return result
```

**Требуется увеличить скорость работы кода выше, или предложить варианты решения задачи** (если не ошибаюсь циклы в Python 3 работают медленно, замены не смог найти/придумать).

**Далее приводится подробное объяснение, что подается в функцию, что она делает, примерно как работает:**

На вход в функцию подается трехмерный массив (массив_1), содержащий N картинок.

У картинки один параметр: яркость пикселя (программно черно-белая картинка, не RGB и т.п.).

Массив может содержать любое количество элементов: N*(X*Y), где X и Y количество пикселей по ширине/высоте, N - количество картинок.

Массив транспонируется до подачи в функцию, для простоты выполнения подсчетов!

Массивы преобразованы в строку (картинка преобразована в строку)!

Реальный массив (частичный), 5 картинок:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Нулевой элемент массива [0]:

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.01176471
  0.07058824  0.07058824  0.07058824  0.49411765  0.53333336  0.68627453
  0.10196079  0.65098041  1.          0.96862745  0.49803922  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.11764706  0.14117648  0.36862746
  0.60392159  0.66666669  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.88235295  0.67450982  0.99215686  0.94901961  0.7647059
  0.25098041  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.19215687
  0.93333334  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.98431373  0.36470589  0.32156864
  0.32156864  0.21960784  0.15294118  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.07058824  0.85882354  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.7764706   0.71372551  0.96862745  0.94509804
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.3137255   0.61176473
  0.41960785  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.80392158  0.04313726  0.
  0.16862746  0.60392159  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.05490196  0.00392157  0.60392159  0.99215686  0.35294119  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.54509807  0.99215686  0.74509805  0.00784314
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.04313726  0.74509805  0.99215686
  0.27450982  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.13725491
  0.94509804  0.88235295  0.627451    0.42352942  0.00392157  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.31764707  0.94117647  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.46666667  0.09803922
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.17647059  0.72941178  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.58823532  0.10588235  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0627451   0.36470589
  0.98823529  0.99215686  0.73333335  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.97647059  0.99215686  0.97647059  0.25098041  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.18039216  0.50980395
  0.71764708  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.81176472  0.00784314  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.15294118  0.58039218  0.89803922
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.98039216  0.71372551  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09411765  0.44705883  0.86666667  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.78823531  0.30588236  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.09019608  0.25882354  0.83529413  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.7764706   0.31764707  0.00784314  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.07058824  0.67058825  0.85882354  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.7647059   0.3137255   0.03529412  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.21568628  0.67450982  0.88627452  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.95686275  0.52156866  0.04313726  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.53333336  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.83137256
  0.52941179  0.51764709  0.0627451   0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

Требуется обработать входной массив другим массивом (массив_2) размером n*m (ширина/высота).

```
Массив_2, пример:
n=3, m=2
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

Алгоритм обработки, очень кратко, подробнее см. на приведенных сайтах в конце вопроса и в коде программы (нейронные сети, краткое объяснение алгоритма работы свертки):

1 - Массив_2 (M_2) ставится в начало Массива_1 (M_1) (нулевые элементы становятся на одной позиции, после чего все элементы перемножаются, результаты произведений суммируются)

```
N и M - размерности M_1
M_1[0][0]*M_2[0][0]+M_1[1][0]*M_2[1][0]+...+M_1[N-1][0]*M_2[N-1][0]+
+M_1[0][1]*M_2[0][1]+M_1[0][1]*M_2[0][1]+...+M_1[N-1][M-1]*M_2[N-1][M-1]
```

2 - Происходит сдвиг индекса в M_2 на 1 "вправо" (+1), повторяется операция 1

```
M_1[0][0]*M_2[1][0]+M_1[1][0]*M_2[2][0]+...+M_1[N-1][0]*M_2[N][0]+
+M_1[0][1]*M_2[1][1]+M_1[0][1]*M_2[1][1]+...+M_1[N-1][M-1]*M_2[N][M-1]
```

3 - При достижении конца строки в M_2, переход на следующую строку.

4 - Операции 1, 2, 3 повторяются пока не будет достигнуты концы строки и столбца M_2.

***Ссылки на теорию нейронных сетей свертки:***

1) (https://habrahabr.ru/post/309508/)

2) (https://habrahabr.ru/company/wunderfund/blog/314872/)

3) (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

***Заранее спасибо!!!***

Comment: Попробуйте использовать pandas. Он, насколько я знаю, написан ан ++. Поэтому всё должно быть быстрее.

Comment: решил попробовать написать код на Cython в виде отдельного модуля, т.к. код на Python с циклами не эффективен